# Is there a new bug with flash 10 player using as2 publishing as an exe projector?

Tags: flash-cs4, projector, cd-rom

I do a lot of cd-roms using as2 but recently when I try to publish an exe file the full screen fs command just now freezes my exe file. I've seen the other post here about double quotes and changing case but is there any other new thing that makes it not work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that projectors rely on the flash player's that your browser does, it's not updated as often as the browser,  It's embedded into the exe.  Thus, unless you've updated flash (the actual program), the version is the same as the one that published your previous projector.  (Assuming you're talking about not previously having this problem)

However, you may have updated your video driver, or something with your operating system that would be causing the lock up.

What you *can* do, is try and see if there *is* an update to your suite.  You also could try reverting to a non updated version if you *did* update.

Besides that, I suggest trying the projector on multiple computers to see if the problem is consistent.